# Winston logger - Is it possible to log the shut down of an application

Tags: logging, docker, winston

In Winston logger for node js, is it possible to log the shut down of a node application? For example, if a node app is run in a docker, and the docker container is killed, is it possible to log that with winston? Or do I need to log it through docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [capture signal events](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) in node.js and run [any code on that signal](http://dailyjs.com/2012/03/15/unix-node-signals/), in your case the logging.

#### SIGTERM - a graceful shutdown in nodejs

A `docker stop` will send a `SIGTERM` signal, and that's the standard 'close all your files and connections and stop the program' signal that is sent to a *nix process. You probably want to handle a `SIGINT` in the same way too (a ctrl-c sends this).

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {  
  winston.log('Got a SIGTERM, exiting');
  process.exit(1);
});
```

#### SIGKILL - not so graceful kill

A `docker kill` or a timeout on `docker stop` will send a `SIGKILL`. You can't capture a `SIGKILL` from node.js as this is the kernels "kill it and don't ask questions" last resort to get rid of a process. To capture some logs for a kill you would need look at dockers logs, or some other external monitoring/logging as kills can come from anywhere (For example a `kill -9` command or the Out Of Memory manager in the kernel).

#### Combining application and Docker logs

You can combine your docker logs with your application logs by using a [docker logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) that matches your [Winston transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md) if they are both logging to a central location. [Syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog), [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/)(gelf) and [Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) are open source log collectors and can be used from both.